# How do i add files into a zip for download?

Tags: java, spring, download, zip, zipoutputstream

My files does not have a path because it is stored in the database. I retrieve it from blob to bytes. Whenever i download the .zip file, the file is invalid and empty even though the size of the .zip file is not 0kb.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadMultipleFilesAsZip", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void downloadMultiAsZip(@RequestParam("selectedFile[]") int[] selectedFiles,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    
                List<FileUpload> fileToDownload = new ArrayList<FileUpload>();
                System.out.println("==================================================");
                for (int i = 0; i<selectedFiles.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Value of multipleFile["+i+"] is " + selectedFiles[i]);
                    FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
                    fu.setFile_id(selectedFiles[i]);
                    fileToDownload.add(fu);
                    System.out.println("fileToDownload file_id is " + fileToDownload.get(i).getFile_id());
                }
                // store details of downloads into fileToDownload
                fileToDownload = fuMapper.downloadMultipleAsZip(fileToDownload);
                
                //Do download
                OutputStream os = null;
                
                try {                  
                    response.setContentType("application/zip");
                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=download.zip");
                    
                    os = response.getOutputStream();
                    
                    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(os);
                    System.out.println("================== Starting zip ==================");
                    for(FileUpload fu : fileToDownload) {
                        System.out.println("Zipping " + fu.getFile_name() + ".....");
                        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fu.getFile_name());
                        
                        os.write(fu.getFile_data());
                        zos.finish();
                        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                        zos.closeEntry();
                        
                        } 
                    System.out.println("================== Finish zipping. ==================");
                    
                    os.flush();
                    zos.close();
                    os.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                        
        }
```

whenever i open the zip file, i have this error

[image]

Comment: You are doing very random stuff in your loop. Why is there a `zos.finish();` in there? Why do you write the file data to `os`, not `zos`? The order in the loop needs to be `putNextEntry`, `write`, `closeEntry`, all performed on the `ZipOutputStream`.

Comment: tbh idk what im doing. i tried using zos.write but is not writing any data.

Answer (score 1):

The flow in the loop is:

1. `putNextEntry`,
2. `write` (to `zos`, not `os`!)
3. `closeEntry`.

After the loop you need to call either `close` or `finish` on `zos`. If not, the ZIP file won't be properly ended. Since its underlying stream is not yours (the container owns it), I'd use `finish`:

```java
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(os);
System.out.println("================== Starting zip ==================");
for(FileUpload fu : fileToDownload) {
    System.out.println("Zipping " + fu.getFile_name() + ".....");
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fu.getFile_name());

    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    zos.write(fu.getFile_data());
    zos.closeEntry();
}
zos.finish();

System.out.println("================== Finish zipping. ==================");

// Don't close zos or os; flushing shouldn't be necessary but won't hurt
```